# SQL query to return rows from one table that don't exist in another

Tags: sql, deployment, oracle11g, production-environment, setup-deployment

I've made a costly and embarrassing mistake recently and I'm d*mned if it's going to happen again. I hope you can help me...here's what happened.

In a deployment to PROD, one of the steps is to make sure all of the `DEV.code_mapping` table rows exist in the `PROD.code_mapping` table.

To do this, I ran the following query (Oracle 11g). I expected it to display every row in `DEV.code_mapping` that did ***not*** exist in PROD.code_mapping.

```
select * FROM code_mapping D 
where D.source_system_id = '&LHDNUMBER'
and not exists
    (select 1 from
    dm.code_mapping@PROD_CHECK P where
    D.mapping_definition_id = P.mapping_definition_id and
    D.cdm_code = P.cdm_code and
    D.source_system_code = P.source_system_code);
```

The query returned zero results.

I falsely concluded that every row in `DEV.code_mapping` existed in `PROD.code_mapping`.

It turns out that in actual fact none of the rows existed in the `PROD.code_mapping` table. The query somehow didn't pick that up. I think it may be because this query can't evaluate against the nulls in PROD, but no amount of `NVL([column],'null')` statements seem to make this work.

How can I make this work???

**ALSO:**

Beside the query correction itself, I'd welcome any best practice pointers you could give me for undertakings like this. I ***REALLY*** don't want a go-live like that again.

Comment: Oracle can confuse `NULL` values with the empty string `''`.  Could this be causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd use a `MINUS`

```
SELECT *
  FROM code_mapping
 WHERE soure_system_id = '&LHDNUMBER'
MINUS
SELECT *
  FROM dm.code_mapping@prod_check
```

`MINUS` handles `NULL` comparisons automatically (a `NULL` on the source automatically matches a `NULL` on the target).

If you want to [list all differences between the two tables](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2151582681236) (i.e. list all rows that exist in dev but not prod and prod but not dev), you can add a UNION ALL

```
(SELECT a.*, 'In dev but not prod' descriptio
   FROM dev_table a
 MINUS 
 SELECT a.*, 'In dev but not prod' description
   FROM prod_table a)
UNION ALL
(SELECT a.*, 'In prod but not dev' descriptio
   FROM prod_table a
 MINUS 
 SELECT a.*, 'In prod but not dev' description
   FROM dev_table a)
```

Comment: that's helpful, but the tables aren't identical across the two environments, so it doesn't quite have the desired effect. I need to detect the rows that have the same `mapping_definition_id`,`mapping_definition_id` and `mapping_definition_id` values across both environemnts.

Comment: @Nimbocrux - You can list out the columns you are interested in if you only want to compare a subset of columns.  Or you can add predicates so that you're only comparing subsets of the rows.  Are you saying that subsetting the columns and the rows is not sufficient for you?  And I'm assuming that you didn't mean to list the same column three times...

Comment: I didn't mean to list the same column three times... correction to previous, should be `mapping_definition_id, cdm_code, source_system_code` - I want to compare these subset of 3 columns.

Comment: @Nimbocrux - Well, then just `select` those three columns rather than doing a `select *`.

Answer (score 3):

Use LEFT JOIN and WHERE myProdField is null.

So for your query, if I'm reading you right, you would have:

```
SELECT D.mapping_definition_id, D.cdm_code, D.source_system_code FROM code_mapping D
LEFT JOIN dm.code_mapping@PROD_CHECK P
  ON D.mapping_definition_id = P.mapping_definition_id
    AND D.cdm_code = P.cdm_code
    AND D.source_system_code = P.source_system_code
WHERE P.mapping_definition_id IS NULL
```

That's the general idea anyway. It will not match unless all three conditions are met. So any distinction will give you a row with P fields that are null, including P.mapping_definition_id, which you are filtering on. So this will give you every row in DEV that does not have a complete match in PROD.

As for best practice pointers, the safest way to be sure that your deployment is going to go exactly as you planned is to practice it in an identical environment. If you can afford to set up a Pre-production environment that mirrors Production, you can test the deployment there first to make sure it has done what you expected it to do. Then repeat exactly for Production.